# join table and find and get an specified row laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to get an specified record from a join table, my query is as below

```
$user = Auth::user(); //current authenticated user
$user_id = $user->id; //get the current authenticated user's id
$users = DB::table('users') //join table users and table user_details base from matched id;
    ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.id')
    ->find($user->id) //find the record matched to the current authenticated user's id from the joint table records
    ->get(); //get the record
dd(var_dump($users)); //dump result
```

but unfortunately sadly it gives me this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join `user_details` on `users`.`id` = `user_details`.`id` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

so i bet my query is wrong LOL! anyway, any help, ideas please?

Comment: It doesn't know what table `id` belongs to in the where clause. Change `->find($user->id)` to `->where("users.id", "=", $user->id)` and it should work for you.

Comment: @Uchiha 's answer is correct, however, why not use [Eloquent relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) as is convention with Laravel, and make life easier? You'd create a Detail model, with its records on a details database table, and define that a User hasOne Detail. Then, you could $user->load('detail') on your second line of code and be done with it.

Comment: that would be cool but im still learning that relationship model thing as of now, as my current knowledge, this is the best I could do in this fast phase projects i have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error itself depicts that on which tables `id` should it place condition so you need to replace your `find` with `where` like as

```
->where("users.id",$user->id)
```

instead of

```
->find($user->id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'user_id' in user_details table (not only 'id'), because
it doesn't know what table id belongs to in the where clause.

1. change `id` to `user_id` in your `user_details` table
2. try this: `->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.user_id')`

If you don't want to change your db:
Replace `->find($user->id)` with `->where("users.id", "=", $user->id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use `where()` method instead of `find()` method.
This will work.

Comment: Please add some explanation - why does this work? Such explanation will help the OP to learn what went wrong