# Error: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 when Join in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to join two table together by specifying their relationship (i.e foreign key and local key) and using find(id). Ab initio, I used where and get(). It didn't gave the same error then I commented out the where clause to use find($id)

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `votes`.`flavour`, `users`.`email` from `votes` inner join `users` on `votes`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = 1 limit 1)",
```

This is the function for displaying based on the selection 
public function show($id)
        {

```
         $dbconnect = DB::table('votes')
         ->join('users', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
         //->where('votes.id', $id)
         ->select('votes.id','votes.date_of_birth','votes.voter_ip','votes.flavour', 'users.email')
         ->find($id);
         $vote = auth()->user()->$dbconnect;
        if (!$vote) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Vote with id ' . $id . ' not found'
            ], 400);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $vote->toArray()
        ], 400);
    }
```

**Show all:** in this function I am supposed to use join as well but I only used votes table it displayed accurately I need to join the votes and users table on votes.user_id = users.id

```
public function index()
        {
            $votes = auth()->user()->votes;

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $votes
            ]);
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join table and find and get an specified row laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038853/join-table-and-find-and-get-an-specified-row-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using the `->find($id)` function. This function will look for the primary key of the model (in this case `id`) and use this as the filter. However, because of the join, this field is ambiguous.

To solve this, you can add the filter manually:

```
$dbconnect = DB::table('votes')
     ->join('users', 'votes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
     ->select('votes.id','votes.date_of_birth','votes.voter_ip','votes.flavour', 'users.email')
     ->where('votes.id', $id)
     ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, it is displaying error:  "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: It is complaining of $vote = auth()->user()->$dbconnect; error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: That line doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to ensure the user is authenticated.  $vote - auth()-user()

Comment: When I removed it, it displays an error: Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray(). This line in the code "'data' => $vote->toArray()"